# Create a file in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I hava a tomcat java web application. I want to create a file to store some json data in it. How do I create this file and where will this file be created?

```
public void insert(UserProfile profile) {
    JSONObject jsUser = profile.asJSONObject();     

    try {

        String path = profile.getUsername()+".json";
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path);

        fileWriter.write(jsUser.toJSONString());
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I create this file ...

Use the standard Java I/O libraries to create and write the file; e.g. you could use a FileWriter.

> ... and where will this file be created?

It is entirely up to you to decide where you want the file to be created.

However, you need to beware of the possibility that someone might trash your web service by causing it to fill up the file system ... or by causing it to write stuff on top of some (important) existing file.  You need a good strategy for dealing with these concerns, but that will depend on the purpose of these files, and the circumstances under which they are written.

Comment: I use a FileWriter but no file appears ... Can you explain what path I should use. I add the code to my question.

Comment: I can't tell you what path to use unless you say where you want the file to be written.

Comment: I would like it in my project folder

Comment: Well use the absolute pathname of your project folder.  The Tomcat webapp has no way of knowing what this is, so you will need to hard wire it into your code (>>ick<<) or set it via a custom configuration property.